# get HTMLUnitDriver bypass untrusted certificate verification (Selenium 2.0)

Tags: java, selenium, https, htmlunit

I have been trying to access an HTTPS URL with the `HTMLUnitDriver` API of Selenium 2.0, but somehow the execution gets stuck at the "This Connection is Untrusted" window and and the control doesn't return back. Following is the code I have tried working on after I got some hint from [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/a9d55bf19f9c2f42):

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(final WebClient client) {
        try {
            client.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }
};
driver.get("https://172.25.194.91:8443/meta/homeScreen.do");
```

I'd highly appreciate any help to get it work .

Comment: SOS SOS ... desp. in need of some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was something else and is resolved now: `HtmlUnitDriver` uses `WaitingRefreshHandler` without parameters and unfortunately that is inappropriate for some sites - for example, `HtmlUnitDriver` hangs on http://news.google.com.

**Cause & Scenario:**

1. You load a page, which refreshes to itself after a period of time, because of the presence of a `<meta http-equiv="refresh"...>` directive in your HTML header.
2. `WaitingRefreshHandler` waits for the time specified but after that time elapses, *it again redirects `HtmlUnitDriver` to get that page!*
3. Consequently, you loop forever in this redirection process.

**Solution:**

One needs to extend the `HtmlUnitDriver` and override the `modifyWebClient` method to set a new (read: to clear the) refresh handler.

```
@Override
protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
    RefreshHandler rh = new RefreshHandler() {
        public void handleRefresh(final Page page, final URL url, final int seconds) { }
    };
    client.setRefreshHandler(rh);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: I'm using HtmlUnitDriver 2.28.2 and this solution does not work: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider SunJCE`